# asp.net website : Init funciton taking longer time

Tags: asp.net, performance

Below is the trace of my web page. This request is made after the browser is opened. However, When the page is refreshed, the init takes few milliseconds.After this, when i close the browser and open the page again, it is taking 1.5 to 2 secs. 
When i keep the browser idle for some 10 mins, and then try to load the page in same window, same tab, it take 1.5 to 2 seconds.

Could some one help me to find why is it taking long time, and how to fix it.. Thanks in advance.

The site is a "ASP.NET Website", running under IIS7. There are no compiled DLLs. We just host the code in IIS and it compiles when the page is requested for first time.

Thanks in Advance

```
aspx.page Begin PreInit   
aspx.page End PreInit            1.4806351086E-05 0.000015 
aspx.page Begin Init             3.2406353321E-05 0.000018 
aspx.page End Init               2.01821376739222 2.018181 
aspx.page Begin InitComplete     2.01825399596876 0.000040 
aspx.page End InitComplete       2.01826936105008 0.000015 
aspx.page Begin PreLoad          2.01828025628956 0.000011 
aspx.page End PreLoad            2.01858532299496 0.000305 
aspx.page Begin Load             2.01860404045766 0.000019 
aspx.page End Load               3.1689460531995  1.150342 
aspx.page Begin LoadComplete     3.1689762246319  0.000030 
aspx.page End LoadComplete       3.16898879606207 0.000013 
aspx.page Begin PreRender        3.16901561511309 0.000027 
aspx.page End PreRender          3.17915796560736 0.010142 
aspx.page Begin PreRenderComplete3.17918115291189 0.000023 
aspx.page End PreRenderComplete  3.18084616899634 0.001665 
aspx.page Begin SaveState        3.21169562053278 0.030849 
aspx.page End SaveState          3.21362435728563 0.001929 
aspx.page Begin SaveStateComplete3.21364670649482 0.000022 
aspx.page End SaveStateComplete  3.21365816046453 0.000011 
aspx.page Begin Render           3.21366849697378 0.000010 
aspx.page End Render             3.28394558526293 0.070277
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be lots of reasons for why you are having those performance issue. If you are not using a precompiled web it is normal that it takes longer to satisfy the first request. But after that if the user request the same resource it should be much quicker. It difficult answer you question because there could be lots of reasons why you are having this issue only if the user starts a new session :

- The browser could have cached the page or you are using any kind of output cache
- Your code could do something very heavy on the session_onStart
- we don't know what you do with each page events
  In general to improve the compilation time you could go for a an Asp.net precompiled web site
  but it not sure it will solve your issue

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/399f057w%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: do you mean using a Web Application as opposed to a Web Site project for precompilate?

Comment: technically  WebApplication and web site are the same thing. In VS world they are used for different goals:http://maordavid.blogspot.com/2007/06/aspnet-20-web-site-vs-web-application.html
Anyway you should use a WebSite template to use the precompiled feature

Comment: I'm pretty sure the Web Application template is the one with precompilation.  Web site is compiled dynamically per-page.

Comment: you can prebuild both of them. it is just different the result you will have.

Comment: Ok, I see what you're saying.  But Web Applications are inherently precompiled into DLL files.  I see how you can force precompilation on a Web Site though.

Comment: @Peluso: Thanks for d suggestions. But the problem i face is still a different one, apart from your solution, bcoz,
1. If the browser is caching the page, i dont think it affects the init which is server side.
2. This page is not initiating the session, but by login page and redirected here.
3. Pre-compile would help a faster response only during the 1st hit for the page after deploying. But this is happening first hit of the page every time a new browser is opened.
But your output cache gave me a thought. Is it something related to the no. of controls in my page. Coz its more than 1000 now.